# how can I make a queue allows only one consumer in ActiveMQ

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic

I want there is only zero or one consumer connected to a queue , if a new consumer want to connect to this queue , the previous consumer's connection will be closed and the new consumer will connect to this queue. How can I do that ?  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think ActiveMQ supports this out of the box.  You could write a BrokerPlugin that kept track of consumers and injected a removeConsumer call for the old consumer within the addConsumer action for the new one.  I'm not sure how this would affect the first consumer.

But why do you want to do this?  Is having just one consumer enough?  Do you have to have a new consumer request replace an old one?  If not, you should just use [exclusive consumers](http://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer.html).